# Find keys in a dictionary of lists using values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary that contains multiple values per a key. I would like to use one of the values to get all the keys associated with the value. However my code runs with a null response.

```
def dict_keys(my_dict, *vals):
for k, v in my_dict.items():
    if v == ['vals']:
        return key
    else:
        return 'No keys' 
return dict_keys
```

dict_keys(fruit_dict, 'melon', 'strawberries')

```
'No keys'
```

However I cannot, grab a single value within a list:

```
for key, value in fruit_dict.items():  
    print(value)
    print(value == 'melon')
 
output:

['melon', 'berry', 'mango']
False
['orange']
False
['lime']
False
['berry', 'watermelon', 'strawberry']
False
['cherry', 'melon']
False
```

Comment: iterate over the values with a second loop!

Comment: 1. `v == [...]` isn't how you check if `v` is _one of the members_ in the list. 2. `vals` is already a list. You don't need to wrap it in brackets. And anyway, your `['vals']` is a list that contains a _single string_ -- the string `'vals'`

Comment: This is kinda a long shot but from your first code snippet, change the `if v == ['vals']:` to `if v in ['vals']:` and see if it works.

Comment: I would suggest the OP getting a basic course of Python: Difference between using brackets and not, meaning of single quotes to create strings, checking membership in lists... Us telling you the errors in that simple code snippet will not help you learn how to program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `v == [...]` isn't how you check if `v` is *one of the members* in the list.
2. `vals` is already a list. You don't need to wrap it in brackets. And anyway, your `['vals']` is a list that contains a *single string* -- the string `'vals'`
3. You want *all* keys that contain the fruit, so you need to *finish the loop* and `return` the list of keys *after* you've processed all keys.
4. Your function's return type should be consistent. To return something that indicates nothing, it's better to return `None`. In this case, since we're returning a *list*, it's better to just return an empty list.
5. You want to pass a *single* fruit and get all the keys that contain that fruit.
6. I suggest you use *descriptive* names for variables. For example, in `for k, v in my_dict.items()`, `k, v` doesn't really tell you what those variables are, but if you rename them to something that makes sense, it's easier to understand what your code is meant to be doing.

```
def dict_keys(my_dict, search_fruit):
    keys = [] # Initialize an empty list
    for person, liked_fruits in my_dict.items():
        if search_fruit in liked_fruits: # Check if the list contains the fruit you're looking for
            keys.append(person)
        else:
            # Do nothing
            pass
    return keys
```

Now suppose you have a dictionary like so, which tells you the favorite fruit of five people, and you want to find the people that like melon:

```
fruit_dict = {
 "A": ['melon', 'berry', 'mango'],
 "B": ['orange'],
 "C": ['lime'],
 "D": ['berry', 'watermelon', 'strawberry'],
 "E": ['cherry', 'melon']
}
```

You'd do:

```
dict_keys(fruit_dict, "melon")
```

which would give you a list containing two keys:

```
 ['A', 'E']
```

Comment: I tried running this code, and the output is an empty list

Comment: @elly_jelly How did you run it?

Answer (score 1):

iterate over the values with a second loop!

```py
for key, fruits in fruit_dict.items():
    for fruit in fruits:
        if fruit == test_fruit:
            ...
```

or check for membership

```py
for key, fruits in fruit_dict.items():
    if test_fruit in fruits:
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `set.intersection` and save yourself a nested loop:

```
def keys_with_vals(my_dict, *vals):
    check_vals = set(vals).intersection
    return [k for k, v in my_dict.items() if check_vals(v)]
```

Comment: @elly_jelly Great! if this works for you please consider marking it as the answer so others can be helped as well as crediting me for the answer.